# iFrame in a Content Editor Web Part

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm creating a page with two web parts: one with a search UI and another that displays the results.  I'm using Content Editor Web Parts for both, but no matter how hard I try I can't seem to display more than a fraction of the results page in the content editor web part with the iFrame.  The width seems to set fine, but no matter how I set the height (I've tried in-line, using CSS and using Javascript/JQuery), I cannot change the height of what is displayed.  If I make the height something ridiculous like 3000px, I can see the empty space below, but it still only shows a small amount of the resulting page at the top of this iframe section.

I've observed the HTML and the iFrame takes up all the space it's supposed to, but only shows that small sliver of the actual page the iFrame is displaying.  I've tried numerous approaches from numerous articles but have come up short (pun intended).

Does anyone have any experience with this or have indication as to why it would display this way or what I have to do to make this iFrame fill up the entire web part space?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If setting a width and height on your iframe as i have it below is not working

```
<iframe width="200px" height="200px...></iframe>
```

That means it's a styling problem with your content. What does your content look like.

Comment: The content is the results of a search.  When I load it up in a browser it shows the full page.  I'm not applying any styles to the content.  All I do is set the src attribute of the iFrame to the results of the query

Comment: if your inner content is not styled or wrapped with any element, then you should consider wrapping it with a div element that has a width and height properties. ex:  `<div style="width: 400px; height:400px;">content...</div>`. See how that works for you.

Comment: Thanks Hussein -  I did find that I had to adjust the height of the parent div and have confirmed that if I load a google page, the full page will show up.  However, the result page of my query still exhibits different behavior by only showing up in about 50px height of the iframe (width is fine).  My next step is to try to catch the onload event of the iframe so I can try to adjust the height after it's loaded.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @music, you can force the height of the content to adjust to the height of your iframe using jQuery. You can do `$('#content').height(('iframe').height());` where `#content` is the id of your content inside iframe.